# Disable check box if there is an img element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Need to disable the checkbox and line through the checkbox text if there is an img element (before the checkbox element) with data- attribute and if checkbox not checked.

```
<div class="classContainer">  
    <label>
        <img data-disable-checkbox="true">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            This checkbox value
    </label>
    <label>        
        <input type="checkbox" />
       This checkbox value
    </label>
    <label>
        <img data-disable-checkbox="true">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        This checkbox value
    </label>
</div>  



var img = $("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']");
        if (!(img.next("input").is(":checked"))){            
            img.next().prop("disabled", true);
            img.parent().contents().filter(function(){
                return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text());
            }).wrap($('<span />', {
                style: 'text-decoration: line-through'
            }));
        }
```

I have tried it in http://jsfiddle.net/yXVZM/9/

How can I add the desired behavior explained above?

Comment: Try `(img.next("checkbox")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you aren't iterating over each images, instead you're just running the code only on the first image.

I've added an `.each()` below to loop through each image in the set:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e9YdT/2/)

```
var img = $("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']");
img.each(function(index, val){
    if (!($(this).next("input").is(":checked"))){   
        $(this).next().prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).parent().contents().filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text());
        }).wrap($('<span />', {
            style: 'text-decoration: line-through'
        }));
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$(".test").each( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if($this.find("img").length) {
        $this.find("input:checked").prop("disabled", "true");
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yXVZM/14/

**Edit:** apparently I misread and thought checked rather than **not** checked and didn't catch the strike-thru - for that:

http://jsfiddle.net/yXVZM/19/

```
$(".test").each( function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if($this.find("img").length) {
        $notChecked = $this.find("input:checkbox").not(":checked");
        if($notChecked.length) {
            $notChecked.prop("disabled", "true");
            $this.attr("style","text-decoration: line-through");
        }
    }
});
```

This was based on the fact you have the class for each label in your fiddle. You could do something similar if you don't have the class in your code... or just add a class.

Or use a selector like this instead `$(".classContainer").children().each(....`

Answer (score 1):

I added labels and a CSS class for this, how about:

JS:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    var image = $(this).prev("img[data-disable-checkbox]").length;
    var isChecked = this.checked;

    if (image && !isChecked) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).next("label").addClass("cbDisabled");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.cbDisabled {
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yXVZM/16/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).next('input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true).prop('nextSibling');
    $(n).wrap('<span class="strike"/>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gwJYN/

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<label>
    <img data-disable-checkbox="true">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    This checkbox value
</label>
```

To:

```
<label class="test">
    <img data-disable-checkbox="true">
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk" /> <span>
            This checkbox value        
        </span>
</label>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('img').length > 0) {
            if ($(this).find('.chk').not(":checked")) {
                $(this).find('.chk').prop("disabled", true);
                $(this).find('.chk').next('span').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cCRuV/)